# Не получается вызвать функцию с передаваемой информацией

Tags: python

```py
import requests
import ast


def getQueueStats():
    url = "https://api.anti-captcha.com/getQueueStats"
    header = {"Content-type": "application-json"}
    data = {"queueId": 2}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=header, json=data)
    info = ast.literal_eval(response.text)
    inf = info
    # print(f"Ожидающие: {info['waiting']}\nСкорость: {info['speed']}")
    return info, inf

def printer(info):
    print(f"Ожидающие: {info['waiting']}\nСкорость: {info['speed']}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    getQueueStats()
    printer()
```

Вот есть код. В функции `getQueueStats` я получаю запросом информацию и мне эту информацию нужно передать в функцию printer чтобы она обработала и вывела эти значения, пробую пробую не получается, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: ну так передавай, ты ж 1) не получаешь информацию, 2) ничего не передаешь в printer()

Comment: import requests
import ast


def getQueueStats():
    url = "https://api.anti-captcha.com/getQueueStats"
    header = {"Content-type": "application-json"}
    data = {"queueId": 2}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=header, json=data)
    info = response.text
    return info

def printer(info):
    info = ast.literal_eval(info)
    print(f"Ожидающие: {info['waiting']}\nСкорость: {info['speed']}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    getQueueStats()
    printer(getQueueStats())

Вот как решил проблему, теперь все работает. info убрал т.к не строка а преобразую в словарь.

Comment: @poseidonskiy не пишите код в комментарии, пишите ответ

Comment: @Dmitry Да нормальный у вас ответ, зря удалили. Даже если что-то не сойдётся - пусть автор вопроса разбирается, что он хочет передать, механизм вы ему показали

Answer (score -1):

Это достаточно просто

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":   
    info, inf = getQueueStats()
    printer(info)
```

Функция `getQueueStats()` возвращает два значения. Вы можете присвоить эти значения переменным в `main`, а далее используете эту переменную для вызова функции `printer`

Comment: а итоге в инфо только одно значение, а printer() ждет там два

Comment: @Эникейщик та ну разбираться, зачем вот это вот `inf = info`. Не понятно какие данные нужны, как они выглядят.